# How to turn off vibrate only in Notification

Tags: android

I want to turn off vibrate only in notification but vibrate must turn on in ringtone.

The AudioManager only has setRingerMode with RINGER_MODE_NORMAL, RINGER_MODE_SILENT, or RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE.

How can I do?

Comment: PL post some code here what you have tried so far so community will try to solve you problem asap.

Answer (score 0):

Tell your Email program what you want.  Open Email, Menu, Account Settings, Notification Settings, unclick so box is gray.  No more sounds when email arrives!